# Is Email is a char by char datatransfer?

Tags: email, asynchronous, networking, communication, telecommunication

I have a confusion about char by char data transfer vs block by block data transfer. Is email is char by char data transfer ? If email transfer is a char by char transfer,is it Asynchronous transmission ?

Answer (score 0):

There might be some context that's missing from your question, but there are many levels to look at.

The "send email" behavior from libraries will submit the email as an array/block of characters.  At some point that will probably be converted to a stream, which can be seen as a char-by-char transfer.  But when it gets down to the TCP/IP layer, the information is broken into packets with a max size.  But below that layer, the packets are sent one bit at a time.

I hope that covers enough detail to answer your question...if not, we'll probably need more detail to figure out what you're really wanting to kno.

Comment: Email is asynchronous or synchronous transmission ?

Comment: That's almost guaranteed to be a situational thing.  Email APIs tend to allow for both options now-a-days.